# Chrome Extension Modify FormData

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
if (details.method === "POST") {
    var bodyObj = details['requestBody'];
    // I can see/modify bodyObj.formData, but
}
}, {
urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, [
"blocking", "requestBody"
]););
```

How can I return a modified formData?

I see from Chrome Extensions's documentation that I can cancel a request, redirect a request, or modify the request headers, but how can I change the formData?

Comment: This is not possible with the `webRequest` API. Do you want to capture data from the `FormData` API, or just any form data?

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 4):

Based on http://crbug.com/91191, it looks like there's **only read-only access to POST data** for webRequest's onBeforeRequest listeners.

It means we can see what is being sent in a request BODY like this below:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    console.log(details['requestBody']);
}, {
urls: ["<all_urls>"]
}, [
"blocking", "requestBody"
]);
```

But we can't update it for now.

Comment: If this still current with [onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeSendHeaders), or not?